# Save text from specified tags into text file?

Tags: node.js, saving-data

I want to copy text from a particular div class, and save it externally, and then click a button, before repeating the process, to copy the content from an online quiz.

Only, the URL does not change, and the content is updated dynamically. I tried an iFrame so I could simulate button presses with jQuery but the content wouldn't load over it, and I'm not sure I could do so with node.JS because the URL is static.

Any suggestions as to how I could do it, whether it be a Chrome extension or just a program?

Thanks

Comment: You should post some code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Haven't got anything at the moment as not sure if its technically doable in Node.JS (I am a novice, but have asked someone more experienced and was told it can't be done), so I would appreciate any suggestions :)